# How to split a string into an array of strings using regex, storing the regex and not storing the result of it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

For example, there is a line:

```
const string = "a {{bcd}} e {{f}}"
```

The result will be an array like this:

```
const result = ["a", "{{bcd}}", "e", "{{f}}"];
```

I tried the following code, but the regex result was sent to the array.

```js
let string = "a {{bcd}} e {{f}}"

string = string.replace(/\s+/g, "");
const reg = /(\{\{(.*?)\}\})/g
const a = string.split(reg);
console.log(a);
```

It turns out that it still saves the regex, but this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result, you can use a combination of regular expressions and the `match` method. Here's a code example that splits the input string into an array while keeping the "((...))" parts intact:

```js
const inputString = "a ((bcd)) e ((f))";
const regex = /(\(\([^)]+\)\))/g;

const result = inputString.split(regex).filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

In this code:

1. We define the input string `inputString` as `"a ((bcd)) e ((f))"`.
2. We define a regular expression `regex` that matches everything between "((...))" while excluding the parentheses themselves.
3. We use the `split` method to split the input string using this regular expression. This will result in an array where the "((...))" parts are separated.
4. We use `filter(Boolean)` to remove any empty strings from the resulting array.
5. Finally, we print the `result` array, which should contain the desired output: `["a", "((bcd))", "e", "((f))"]`.

This code should give you the expected result.

Comment: And with curly braces like?

Comment: @John1998 can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: If I change the parentheses to curly braces?

Comment: I think I found it, without parentheses it’s just regex: /(\{\{.*?\}\})/g

Comment: Is this AI-generated?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String::matchAll()` to iterate all matches in a string and collect the capture groups:

```js
let string = " a {{bcd}} e {{f}}"

const reg = /\s*(.*?)\s*(\{\{.*?\}\})/g;
const result = []
for(const m of string.matchAll(reg)){
  result.push(...m.slice(1));
}

console.log(result);
```

An one-liner:

```js
console.log( [..."a {{bcd}} e {{f}}".matchAll(/\s*(.*?)\s*(\{\{.*?\}\})/g)].flatMap(m => m.slice(1)) );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**
You could define the multiple combination of regex to match either "((...))" or any other character to capture all the possible substrings.

After you get all the possible substrings in list, filter those empty using *filter*

**Code**

```
// Method 1: Regex by (()) after removing spaces
string = "a ((bcd)) e ((f))"
string = string.replace(/\s+/g, "");
reg = /(\(\([^)]+\)\))/g
a = string.split(reg).filter(Boolean);  
console.log(a)

// Method 2: Regex by (( )) with spaces
string = "a ((bcd)) e ((f))"
reg = /(\(\([^)]*\)\))|\s+/g
a = string.split(reg).filter(Boolean);
console.log(a)

// Method 3: Regex by Spaces
string = "a ((bcd)) e ((f))"
/* string = string.replace(/\s+/g, ""); */
reg = /\s+/g
a = string.split(reg);
console.log(a)
```